# How to rewrite simple SQL condition for better performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have a simple query below to select available assets from a table based on their checkout and expected return date. If the checkout and expected return date overlaps with the `@RentStartDate` and `@RentEndDate` then I want to select it as `UnavailableAsset`. Please see my query below

```
set @RentStartDate = '2016-10-13';
set @RentEndDate = '2016-10-18';

SELECT AssetID as UnAvailableAsset
FROM agreementasset
WHERE (CheckOutDate >= @RentStartDate AND CheckOutDate <= @RentEndDate)
OR
(ExpectedReturnDate >= @RentStartDate AND ExpectedReturnDate <= @RentEndDate)
OR
(@RentStartDate >= CheckOutDate AND @RentEndDate <= ExpectedReturnDate);
```

Now i know that this query works perfectly, but I'm just not sure if there is a better way to write the conditions in the `where` clause.
Is there a better way to simplify the conditions to make this query more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: Which database engine? Have you checked the query plan to see what it's doing?

Comment: Table definition, incl indexes etc?

Comment: Although most likely not giving better performance but better readability, you could replace `(CheckOutDate >= @RentStartDate AND CheckOutDate <= @RentEndDate)` with `CheckOutDate BETWEEN @RentStartDate AND @RentEndDate` and `(ExpectedReturnDate >= @RentStartDate AND ExpectedReturnDate <= @RentEndDate)` with `ExpectedReturnDate BETWEEN @RentStartDate AND @RentEndDate`.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the syntax used

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of what you are doing, I don't understand why you think your query works.

The overlap query should look like this:

```
SELECT AssetID as UnAvailableAsset
FROM agreementasset
WHERE CheckOutDate <= @RentEndDate AND
      ExpectedReturnDate >= @RentStartDate;
```

This type of query can be difficult to optimize (in most databases).  You can start with an index on `agreementasset(CheckOutDate, ExpectedReturnDate, AssetID)`.

Comment: I've tried this query before. It only select the asset that have both checkout and expectedReturndate fall into the range of rent dates.

What i meant by overlapping is, even if either a checkout or an expectedreturndate falls into the range of rent date, that asset would be unavailable

Comment: Looks like indexing is the way to go.

Comment: @Vibol . . . Read the query closely.  This is the logic for any overlap in the time periods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `BETWEEN` keyword?

```
SELECT AssetID as UnAvailableAsset
FROM agreementasset
WHERE (CheckOutDate BETWEEN @RentStartDate AND @RentEndDate)
OR (ExpectedReturnDate BETWEEN @RentStartDate AND @RentEndDate)
```

Comment: You forgot to include the last `OR
(@RentStartDate >= CheckOutDate AND @RentEndDate <= ExpectedReturnDate)`. This case isn't covered by your predicates. (At least not if you don't have more insight into the intended predicate logic.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can streamline and no duplicate conditions

```
SELECT AssetID as UnAvailableAsset
FROM agreementasset
WHERE (@RentStartDate <= CheckOutDate       AND @RentEndDate >= CheckOutDate)
   OR (@RentStartDate >= CheckOutDate       AND @RentEndDate <= ExpectedReturnDate)
   OR (@RentStartDate <= ExpectedReturnDate AND @RentEndDate >= ExpectedReturnDate);
```